# UINavigationController: pop view controller in the opposite direction

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to call `[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` but making the animation slide right to left instead of left to right. Any easy way to do this? I want to return to the previous view. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible, look at the following code I used a while back and try to make it work for yourself. Yu only need to change the `setAnimationTransition`

```
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

There are a few different kind of default animations to use, apples site says this kind of animations are possible:

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

So in your case you would want to use the following:

```
    [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to slide it as if you were calling `pushViewController`?

Comment: Yes like i said, you only need to change the line here: [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

Comment: I understand that. I can't find the correct transition though.

Comment: It's just that none of those do what I want them to do. I want it to have exactly the same motion as if the UINavigationController was pushing a new view controller

Comment: It does, i will edit my post to make this animation, this will be exactly what you want.

Comment: Your solution does something weird. It pops the view without any animation but only the title on the Navigation Bar slides in, not the view itself. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know what your code is, but basically what i did there is exactly what you want to use, try to edit it to your own code.

Comment: Did not. That's okay, though, I ended up going with a different UI strategy. Thanks for the help! Will accept your answer so you can get the points.

Answer (score 18):

This is how one can pop view controller in opposite direction. Its working for me 100%

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.45;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: this is what I was looking!! Thanks.

Comment: You set the type twice? `transition.type = kCATransitionPush` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
    let animation = CATransition()
    animation.duration = 0.3
    animation.type = .push
    animation.subtype = .fromRight
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    navigationController?.view.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```