# Customizing the Popping of a View Controller Xcode

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have an application in Xcode 4.6 that uses storyboards. Inside my application I have two relevant view controllers: one that asks a question and one that presents answers to the question that was asked. (Being new to iOS) I originally had it set up so that the question controller push segued to the answer controller, and the answer controller push segued (via a button) to the question controller (for a new question) and so on and so on, thus leading to a giant navigation stack and memory crashes the longer the application was used.

So, I believe I need to do the following: the question controller should segue to answer controller and then I need the answer controller to POP back to the question controller BUT with a new question image. I put code to reset the image in the viewWillAppear method of the question controller which works fine, but here is a problem: I don't ALWAYS want to reset the image every time the question controller appears. I only want it to reset if an answer in the answer controller has been selected. I tried setting a bool property on the question controller FROM the answer controller to conditionally reset the view, but this does not work.

A second problem is that I need to pop back to the question controller for memory sake, but I'd like to give the illusion of a push segue for style sake. I don't know if this is possible.

In short, my two main questions are:
**1) Is it possible to conditionally reset the view for a controller I am popping to?**

**2) Is it possible to animate a view controller pop from right to left rather than left to right?**

Can anyone answer these questions for me, or even suggest a totally different solution to the ultimate memory issue I am trying to solve?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Sounds like a job for delegation to me. In your answers VC, you would declare a `protocol` and an iVar for the delegate.  Something like this:

```
@protocol AnswerDelegate
- (void)answerSelected:(NSString *)answer forQuestion:(NSString *)passedQuestion;
@end
```

Then add the delegate property and weak iVar, (added a public property for the question also):

```
@interface MyAnswerViewController : UIViewController {
    __unsafe_unretained id <AnswerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AnswerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *passedQuestion;
```

Then in the implementation file for `MyAnswerViewController`, you would fire off the delegate method when the answer is given:

```
[self.delegate answerSelected:@"Answer" forQuestion:@"PassedQuestion"];
```

In the Question VC, all you need to do is declare yourself as a delegate for that Protocol:

```
@interface MyQuestionViewController : UIViewController <AnswerDelegate>
```

And then somewhere in the implementation file, implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)answerSelected:(NSString *)answer forQuestion:(NSString *)passedQuestion {
  // Do something with the question and answer
  // Pop the VC if needed
}
```

This is a pretty straightforward way to deal with passing back objects to calling classes.

2.This one would require implementing your own animations for the transition.  See the SO post below:

[UINavigationController: pop view controller in the opposite direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030930/uinavigationcontroller-pop-view-controller-in-the-opposite-direction)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using delegation just now, but the delegate method does not get fired. I do not know why, I have all of the pieces in place. This is the same issue I had when trying to use a pointer to the question class inside the answer class to set a property on the question class...

Comment: Make sure to set your QuestionVC as a delegate for the AnswerVC in your prepareForSegue method: AnswerVC *avc = segue.destinationViewController;  avc.delegate = self;

Comment: Ah! I was creating a new pointer rather than using segue.destinationViewController. Thanks!!